# IDispatchMessageInspector on dotnet 5

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to intercept my WCF request in my dotnet 5 application but it seems like the IDispatchMessageInspector doesn't exist in dotnet 5. Any idea what it has been replaced with please?

Thanks

Comment: There is no replacement ... MS are telling us to move to GRPC ... There are some projects like [CoreWCF](https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF) but I'm pretty sure that they are not production ready

Comment: This is for a web project though but probably the same thing applies